# Do I need to test for NaN and inifinity for doubles in Java

Tags: java

I understand that `double`s in Java can take `Double.NaN` or `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` etc.

But is it necessary to check for `Double.isNan` or `Double.isFinite` each time a method accepts a double as a parameter?

I'm making a small project and I think that `Nan` or infinite values will not occur.

Comment: Who is calling these methods?

Comment: It solely depends on whether or not you want your function to check for them. It is necessary if your application absolutely isn't allowed to crash and having `NaN` or  infinite values are possibilities. If it's not the end of the world if the program crashes and the there is a low risk these values even will occur, then skip checking for it. It is completely up to you.